# Testing membership in list of Enum fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I'm trying to check if an Enum is in a list of Enums but it is not working as expected.

If I write the code in a single script and I run it, it works fine:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class X(Enum):
...   A = 'a'
...   B = 'b'
...   C = 'c'
...
>>> s = [X.A, X.B]
>>> x = X.C
>>> y = X.B
>>> x in s
False
>>> y in s
True
```

Yet, in my code, the test doesn't seem to work.
This is what I added to debug the behavior:

```
print(type(node.action.kind), node.action.kind)
print(type(KINDS), type(KINDS[0]), KINDS)
if node.action.kind in KINDS:
    print('FIRST TEST')
elif node.action.kind.value in [i.value for i in KINDS]:
    print('SECOND TEST')
else:
    print('NOT IN KINDS')
```

I would expect it to print `FIRST TEST` when the condition matches yet the code prints `SECOND TEST`:

```
<enum 'ActionKind'> ActionKind.TALK
<class 'list'> <enum 'ActionKind'> [<ActionKind.CALL: 'api_call'>, <ActionKind.WAIT: 'wait'>, <ActionKind.HANGUP: 'hangup'>]
NOT IN KINDS

<enum 'ActionKind'> ActionKind.WAIT
<class 'list'> <enum 'ActionKind'> [<ActionKind.CALL: 'api_call'>, <ActionKind.WAIT: 'wait'>, <ActionKind.HANGUP: 'hangup'>]
SECOND TEST
```

I can't see any apparent difference other than the enum is defined elsewhere and the list of KINDS is populated from imported constants in another file. What is happening? Why can't I test membership in list of Enum with the `in` operator?

Comment: @PatrickArtner The OP is asking about the second part of the output, where `ActionKind.WAIT` is apparently in the `KINDS` list but `node.action.kind in KINDS` returns `False` even though `node.action.kind` is apparently equal to `ActionKind.WAIT`.

Comment: Can you show us how `node.action.kind` and `ActionKind` are defined, and how `KINDS` are populated? You can trim down the irrelevant parts to make a minimal but reproducible example.

Comment: This sounds like you actually have two `ActionKind` enums, possibly due to a circular import involving the main script file.

Comment: Try `print(type(node.action.kind).__module__, type(KINDS[0]).__module__)`.

Comment: @user2357112 I added the print statement and both `__module__` match.

Comment: @blhsing as soon as I copy all the relevant code to a new script it works as expected, I guess it may have to do with imports as user2357112 suggests, I will try to look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. I still don't understand it but I will leave this here in case it helps anyone. The problem was that the enum was being reloaded. Once reloaded, even though the printout for `print(type(node.action.kind).__module__` matched, the enums were not.

The following code is the minimal code that reproduces the error:

```
import mylib.classes
from mylib.classes import *
import mylib.renderer
from mylib.renderer import *

nodes = get_nodes() # from classes
check_nodes(nodes) # from renderer
from importlib import reload
reload(mylib.classes)
reload(mylib.renderer)
check_nodes(nodes) # from renderer
```

The first call to `check_nodes` works fine and `FIRST TEST` is printed. After reloading the modules it stops working and `SECOND TEST` is printed instead. This code is part of a script that runs in the background and reloads the code between iterations in order for changes to make effect. We only use this functionality during development.

If it helps, I am on Python 3.7.0 (default, Oct  2 2018, 09:19:48)
[Clang 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)]

Comment: Yep, reloading would do that. This is one of the many reasons relying on `reload` is a really bad idea. Reloading a module creates new versions of all functions and classes in the module, but it cannot update existing references, instances, or subclasses to use the new versions.